# Javascript: Using accessor properties in object closures

Tags: javascript, closures

I recently learned about composing objects together using functions from reading [this article](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/functional-mixins-composing-software-ffb66d5e731c). Following along, I end up with this code:

```
function withFlying(o) {
  let _isFlying = false;
  return {
    ...o,
    fly () {
      _isFlying = true;
    },
    land () {
      _isFlying = false;
    },
    isFlying () {
        return _isFlying
    }
  }
};

function withWalking(o) {
    let isWalking = false;
    return {
        ...o,
        startWalking() {
            isWalking = true;
            return this
        },
        stopWalking() {
            isWalking = false;
            return this
        },
        isWalking: () => isWalking
    }
}

const bird = withWalking(withFlying({}))
```

Everything here works. However, I would like to be able to call `isFlying` as a property instead of a function:

```
// current (working)
bird.isFlying() // return value of `_isFlying`

// desired
bird.isFlying // return value of `_isFlying`
```

I know that `get` and `set` are keywords that can be used in object literals, and so I tried this:

```
function withFlying(o) {
  let _isFlying = false
  return {
    ...
    get isFlying () {
      return _isFlying
    }
  }
}
```

But it doesn't show the correct value after updating using the other functions. I figured that with the `get` property being a function, closures would apply similar to the other functions. Am I wrong in this assumption? Is there underlying behavior with `get` that I'm not understanding, and is what I'm trying to achieve possible the way I'm doing it now?

Here's a snippet with the code I tried to use:

```js
function withFlying(o) {
  let _isFlying = false;
  return {
    ...o,
    fly () {
      _isFlying = true;
    },
    land () {
      _isFlying = false;
    },
    valueOf_isFlying() {
      return _isFlying;
    },
    get isFlying () {
      return _isFlying
    }
  }
};

function withWalking(o) {
  let isWalking = false;
  return {
    ...o,
    startWalking() {
        isWalking = true;
        return this
    },
    stopWalking() {
        isWalking = false;
        return this
    },
    isWalking: () => isWalking
  }
}


const bird = withWalking(withFlying({}))

// desired
console.log(bird.isFlying) // _isFlying starts false
bird.fly() // should set _isFlying to true
console.log(bird.isFlying) // still returns false
console.log(bird.valueOf_isFlying()) // shows _isFlying is true
```

Comment: Nice one with the updates! And yes, this is non-obvious behavior which is likely to trip other people up, too.

Comment: more about [Object property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you create your new object, you're using spread notation to copy the properties from the original object:

```
return {
    ...o,
    // ...
};
```

The problem with that is it copies the *then-current value* of accessor properties, not the definition of the accessor property. You can see that here:

```js
const obj1 = {
    get example() {
        return 42;
    }
};
console.log("Notice that the property descriptor is for an accessor property:");
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj1, "example"));
const obj2 = {...obj1};
console.log("Notice that the property descriptor is for a simple data property:");
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj2, "example"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

It's very much as though you did:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(o) {
    newObject[key] = e[key];
}
```

`e[key]` gets the then-current value of the property, not the definition of the property.

To fix it, use `Object.getOwnPropertyDesciptors` to get the descriptors of the properties, and use `Object.defineProperties` to define those same properties on the new object. Since you're doing that (and adding more properties) in at least two places, you probably want a utility function:

```
function assignPropertyDescriptors(target, obj, updates) {
    // B
    return Object.defineProperties(
        // A
        Object.defineProperties(
            target,
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj)
        ),
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(updates)
    );
}
```

The "A" `Object.defineProperties` call copies the original object's property descriptors and applies them to the new object. The "B" `Object.defineProperties` call applies the ones you're adding to that new object as well.

But let's generalize that into a loop, similar to `Object.assign` (hence the name `assignPropertyDescriptors`):

```
function assignPropertyDescriptors(target, ...updates) {
    for (const update of updates) {
        Object.defineProperties(
            target,
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(update)
        );
    }
    return target;
}
```

`withFlying` and `withWalking` would then use that worker function, for instance:

```
function withFlying(o) {
    let _isFlying = false;
    return assignPropertyDescriptors({}, o, {
        fly () {
          _isFlying = true;
        },
        land () {
          _isFlying = false;
        },
        get isFlying () {
          return _isFlying
        }
    });
};
```

Here's a complete example:

```js
function assignPropertyDescriptors(target, ...updates) {
    for (const update of updates) {
        Object.defineProperties(
            target,
            Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(update)
        );
    }
    return target;
}

function withFlying(o) {
    let _isFlying = false;
    return assignPropertyDescriptors({}, o, {
        fly () {
          _isFlying = true;
        },
        land () {
          _isFlying = false;
        },
        get isFlying () {
          return _isFlying
        }
    });
};

function withWalking(o) {
    let isWalking = false;
    return assignPropertyDescriptors({}, o, {
        startWalking() {
            isWalking = true;
            return this
        },
        stopWalking() {
            isWalking = false;
            return this
        },
        isWalking: () => isWalking
    });
}

const bird = withWalking(withFlying({}))

console.log(bird.isFlying) // _isFlying starts false
bird.fly() // should set _isFlying to true
console.log(bird.isFlying) // _isFlying is true
```

Comment: Are you allowing multiple updates in `copyAndUpdateObject` and then passing in an empty object as the first arg so you can avoid mutating the original object? And also make it more general?

Comment: @LoganWaite - Basically. Your original code using spread didn't mutate the original object, so I continued with that. The loop is also for generality. If you wanted to avoid creating a new object at every stage, just remove the `{}` argument on each call to `copyAndUpdateObject` (the name of which, I just realized, is outdated -- originally, before posting the answer, I had it creating the target object, then decided I should follow `Object.assign`'s example; I'll change the name).

Comment: E.g., if you want to mutate the object, do `return assignPropertyDescriptors(o, {/*...*/});`